# Select as column from set

Tags: oracle, set, in-clause

I have a large dynamic data set 'AA','BB','TT','XX' etc.

I would like select as follows, any smart way to do this (not loading into a table every time) ?

```
name
----
AA
BB
TT
XX
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: select name from tablename is the most smartest way you're going to find.

Comment: Thanks but I should have mentioned that I don't want to dump into table as this data set changes very frequently. I can perhaps use a IN clause.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Not at all clear what you are asking.  WHat is a data set - rows from a single table?

Comment: There is nothing fancy about data set, I just meant a list of string elements, they are not present in a table, I have them in an excel. I want to select them as single column, multiple rows for various operations I wanted to perform. Thanks